# Convert JSON from web API to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert nested json objects get from 'https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability' into dataframe, but incomplete data is retrieved in the dataframe.

Below are my codes:

```py
    res = requests.get("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability")
    j = res.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(j)
    print(df.head())
```

Below is the incomplete result:
items
0  {'timestamp': '2021-03-10T23:07:27+08:00', 'ca...

I reckon maybe I need to use json_normalize, could someone kindly enlighten?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import copy

res = requests.get("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability")
data = res.json()
lst = data['items'][0]['carpark_data']
normalized = []
for entry in lst:
    temp = entry['carpark_info']
    for idx, x in enumerate(temp):
        _entry = copy.deepcopy(entry)
        del _entry['carpark_info']
        _entry.update(x)
        normalized.append(_entry)
df = pd.DataFrame(normalized)
print(df.head(110))
```

output

```
    carpark_number      update_datetime total_lots lot_type lots_available
0             HE12  2021-03-10T23:41:38         91        C             51
1              HLM  2021-03-10T23:41:18        583        C            477
2              RHM  2021-03-10T23:41:38        322        C             59
3             BM29  2021-03-10T23:41:47         97        C             95
4              Q81  2021-03-10T23:41:26         96        C             73
..             ...                  ...        ...      ...            ...
105             C7  2021-03-10T23:41:47        459        C            221
106            C17  2021-03-10T23:29:09         42        C              0
107            C17  2021-03-10T23:29:09         35        Y             17
108            C17  2021-03-10T23:29:09          1        H              1
109           C20M  2021-03-10T23:41:39        551        C            440
```

Comment: There are 128 instances where there is more than one item in `carpark_info`. This method takes the first one. For example, take a look at indexes 106, 190, and 202 in `lst`.

Comment: @jakub you are right. My code assume that there is only 1 item in `['carpark_info']`. So the question is how to handle them. A proper (?) solution can be to generate N records where N is the len of `['carpark_info']`

Comment: @jakub I have changed the code in order to support your comment.